# In Spring-Kafka which method does the same thing like onPartitionsRevoked?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I know that in Sping-Kafka we have below methods:

void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback);

void onPartitionsAssigned(Map assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback);

void onIdleContainer(Map assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback);

But which one it does the same thing like the native ConsumerRebalanceListener method onPartitionsRevoked?

> "This method will be called before a rebalance operation starts and
>   after the consumer stops fetching data. It is recommended that offsets
>   should be committed in this callback to either Kafka or a custom
>   offset store to prevent duplicate data."

If I want to implement the ConsumerRebalanceListener, how can I pass the KafkaConsumer reference? I only see the Consumer from Spring-Kafka.

=========update======

Hi,Gary when I add RebalanceListener this into the ContainerProperties. I can see that both methods get triggered. however, I got the exception, saying sth like "Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing" Do you have any idea?

=========== update 2 ============

```
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> createContainer(
      ContainerProperties containerProps, IKafkaConsumer iKafkaConsumer) {

    Map<String, Object> props = consumerProps();

    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String>(props);

    **RebalanceListner rebalanceListner = new RebalanceListner(cf.createConsumer());**

    CustomKafkaMessageListener ckml = new CustomKafkaMessageListener(iKafkaConsumer, rebalanceListner);

    CustomRecordFilter cff = new CustomRecordFilter();

    FilteringAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter faml = new FilteringAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter(ckml, cff, true);

    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1500); // 1.5 seconds

    RetryTemplate rt = new RetryTemplate();
    rt.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    rt.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    rt.registerListener(ckml);
    RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter rml = new RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter(faml, rt);

    containerProps.setConsumerRebalanceListener(rebalanceListner);
    containerProps.setMessageListener(rml);
    containerProps.setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    containerProps.setErrorHandler(ckml);
    containerProps.setAckOnError(false);
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
        cf, containerProps);

    container.setConcurrency(1);
    return container;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `RebalanceListener` to the container's `ContainerProperties` that are passed into the constructor.

Comment: Hi,Gary when I add RebalanceListener this into the ContainerProperties. I can see that both methods get triggered. however, I got the exception, saying sth like "Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing" Do you have any idea?

Comment: I assume you are using one of the manual ack modes. You shouldn't have to ack the commits yourself - the container will do so on your behalf before calling your listener - any pending acks that are outstanding before the rebalance will be committed. If you are not seeing that behavior, please share your configuration. See [the code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L391) - your listener is called at line 409 after we commit the outstanding offsets.

Comment: Yes. Gary, I set to auto.commit = false. My listener is implementing AcknowledgingMessageListener and the AckMode is set to AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Gary, I just use the native Kafka Consumer API and I am able to implement the RebalanceListener. but use the Spring-Kafka I still get the exception. I will update my configuration in my post. please take a look.

Comment: I think you might have found a bug. The container (and spring-kafka in general) attempts to make things easier for the developer. To that end, when a rebalance occurs, the container commits any pending acknowledgments (where you have already called `acknowledge()` but they haven't yet been committed); it then calls your listener but does not check to see if your listener has added some more acks - can you show your rebalance listener code? If that's what's going on, please open an Issue on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues).

Comment: I reproduced it, and opened [Issue #268](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/268)

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you can reproduce the issue. :)

Comment: This is fixed in 1.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT if you want to try it; we will release 1.1.4 soon; possibly tomorrow.

Comment: 1.1.4 (and 1.2.0) are now available: [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/07/spring-for-apache-kafka-1-2-0-and-1-1-4-available).

Comment: ya, Gary, i am testing the new 1.2.0 .